# Node.js + mongodb or mongojs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been recently migrating all my apps to node.js, like it should be. And I have been using the mongojs driver, however I recently found that there is a mongodb driver. I was wondering, is there any difference between this two? Performance?

Comment: I would recommend the native node driver produced by mongodb themselves: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native

Comment: the driver itself says it's a "module for mongodb, that emulates the official mongodb API as much as possible." then I assume there's no difference between the 2 of them. and I still recommend the official driver.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mongojs is just simpler in its usage, because some functions and are wrapped and easier to call.

It doesn't affect the performance, but theoretically its a bit slower, because there is an additional function call.

You are good using Node.js and the native driver. For starters and cleaner code mongojs is a good option.

Comment: Good, that is the information I needed. I am going to run a couple of benchmarks and compare this two.

Comment: I haven't done any benchmarks, but I would be surprised if there was more than 1% difference in performance between those two.

Answer (score 1):

MongoJS, is more easy, simple and the final result is not slow.

For the last years i'm using only MongoJS for build API's, with millions of transactions per hour, without problems.